# Need help with PKCS#12 3 key triple des key expansion

Tags: key-derivation, 3des, pkcs8

I am trying to decrypt PKCS8-Shrouded Key Bag inside a PKCS#12 pfx file.

The oid for the encrypted data is PbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES CBC.

Iteration count and salt has been provided within the pfx file, and I know

the password.

As far as I know, 3Key Triple DES needs 3 × 56 = 168 bits of key.

I am not sure what I need to do exactly to generate a 168 key using pbkdf2.

Do I simply generate a 192bit key using pbkdf2 and divide it into 3 parts and

use them as three seprate keys after having ignored parity bits?

Comment: These types of questions are usually not answered here. Maybe https://security.stackexchange.com is more appropriate?

Comment: Not PBKDF2; this scheme is defined in PKCS#12 and uses a derivation more like (but not identical to) PBES1/PBKDF1. See Appendix B in http://www.emclink.net/collateral/white-papers/h11301-pkcs-12v1-1-personal-information-exchange-syntax-wp.pdf
 (note that the IETFized version rfc7292 still has an erratum I am reporting).

Comment: Typically, when we generate a (3 key) 3DES key, yes, we do indeed generate 192 bits of key (and the lsbits end up being ignored).  However, I haven't worked with PKCS#12, and so I won't make this an answer.